# Globally Map "Escape Key" to "jj" in vim (mac)

Tags: macos, vim, keymapping

I have been using vim for awhile but I have not been able to figure out how to map the escape globally - every time I open a file, I have to map the escape key to jj like this:

```
:imap jj <Esc>
```

Is there a way to change the runtime defaults so that Esc is already mapped to jj?

I found the default.vim file, but you cannot edit it on a mac (with standard mac software). Should I download something to edit this file? Is there another easier way?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The place for your local changes is called `.vimrc` and you typically create one in your home directory with the commands you want to execute on startup.

Run `vimtutor` on the (system) command line and spend a few minutes learning how to use this editor. Then dig into the facilities provided by `:help` in Vim. E.g. run `:help vimrc` in Vim.

Comment: I ran the help command. It says the vimrc file is located in my home directory ($HOME/.vimrc). However, when I look at my home directory, I only have the standard folders (documents, pictures, etc.) - nothing related to Vim. I am confused. Do you need to create this file? Why does it say it is stored in the home directory if it needs to be created?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Why does it not show up un the home directory after it has been created?

Comment: Google may be helpful regarding that question.